# Problema con formato de fecha

Tags: java, android, oracle

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación movil en la cual guardo datos en mi base de datos del dispositivo, uno de esos campos es la fecha y la hora pero al momento de querer insertar dichos campos desde mi aplicación a Oracle me marca un error por el formato de la fecha la cual la tengo de la siguiente manera

```
    public static String fecha(){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
    return currentDateandTime;
    }
```

Este metodo lo uso para insetar mis datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y con esta linea es la que mando llamar mi metodo

```
String fechaR = manejoDeDatos.fecha();
manejoDeDatos.registrarResultados(mContext, String.valueOf(intentIdUsuario), resultadoQR, fechaR);
```

Para probar si mi web service inserta, estoy utilizando postman y ahí es donde me marca el error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi stored procedure tengo

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE SP_AR_INSERT_JSON_APP(
  ID_USUARIO IN NUMBER,
  INFORMACION_QR IN NVARCHAR2,
  FECHA IN DATE,
  ID_NUEVO OUT NUMBER )
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO XXVIA_LM_TB_ANES_RESULTADOS
      (NUMB_ID_RESULTADOS, 
       DATE_FECHA_HORA_INICIO, 
       NUMB_ID_USUARIO, 
       VCHA_INFORMACIONQR)
    VALUES 
    (((SELECT NVL(MAX(NUMB_ID_RESULTADOS), 0) FROM XXVIA_LM_TB_ANES_RESULTADOS) + 1),
       FECHA, 
       ID_USUARIO,
       INFORMACION_QR)
       RETURNING NUMB_ID_RESULTADOS INTO ID_NUEVO;
       COMMIT;

END SP_AR_INSERT_JSON_APP;
```

Si necesitan algún otro dato con gusto se los comparto. De pura casualidad alguien sabe como podria resolver dicho error, si me pudieran orientar se los agradeceria mucho.

Comment: Android y Oracle? Como te estás conectando a la bd? Donde esta alojada?

Comment: podrías explicar mejor el problema? insertas en local , desde tu aplicación Oracle? no entiendo

Comment: La aplicación se conecta atraves de un ws @Klaimmore

Comment: debes indicar donde ocurre el error, pon el LogCat de la aplicación al momento del error

Comment: que tipo de datos es DATE_FECHA_HORA_INICIO ? supongo que String? si ese campo lo agregaste al último ,entonces desinstala tu app y vuelve a probar.

Comment: en mi aplicacion es String pero en mi base de datos es tipo DATE, si a mi aplicación le quito la parte de la hora me lo hace sin problemas, pero yo ocupo que me guarde tambien la hora

Comment: prueba desinstalando tu aplicación y vuelvelo a correr, nos avisas.

Comment: pues ya he intentado eso pero no me sirve, al momento de hacer la prueba con postman me marca el error como tal pero en android sólo marca error en el web service

Comment: como obtienes fechaR? la columna DATE_FECHA_HORA_INICIO de SQLite de que tipo es (TEXT or INTEGER)? dices que es de tipo DATE pero esta no existe

Comment: La obtengo con String fechaR = manejoDeDatos.fecha();, en SQLite es String pero en Oracle es tipo Date @armen

Comment: en SQLite la columna debe de ser de tipo TEXT (no hay String). Cambia el formato con un nuevo new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") ya que tengo entendido que el formato Date en Oracle es : YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS

Comment: así esta pero aún no logro hacer que me inserte, el problema es que no arroja un error como tal. El error lo vi pero cuando utilizo postman y trato de insertar @armen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es:

```
ORA-01861: El literal no coincide con la cadena de formato.
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string.
```

ocurre en tu Stored Procedure al tratar de insertar la "fecha" en un formato que es incorrecto, el formato que usas para enviar como fecha a tu método del Web Service es :

```
"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
```

por lo tanto modifica tu Stored Procedure  para convertir el valor de `FECHA` a date mediante el método [TO_DATE()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm)

```
TO_DATE(FECHA, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')
```

---

Este sería el cambio en el SP:

```
   create or replace PROCEDURE SP_AR_INSERT_JSON_APP(
  ID_USUARIO IN NUMBER,
  INFORMACION_QR IN NVARCHAR2,
  FECHA IN DATE,
  ID_NUEVO OUT NUMBER )
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO XXVIA_LM_TB_ANES_RESULTADOS
      (NUMB_ID_RESULTADOS, 
       DATE_FECHA_HORA_INICIO, 
       NUMB_ID_USUARIO, 
       VCHA_INFORMACIONQR)
    VALUES 
    (((SELECT NVL(MAX(NUMB_ID_RESULTADOS), 0) FROM XXVIA_LM_TB_ANES_RESULTADOS) + 1),
       TO_DATE(FECHA, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'), 
       ID_USUARIO,
       INFORMACION_QR)
       RETURNING NUMB_ID_RESULTADOS INTO ID_NUEVO;
       COMMIT;

END SP_AR_INSERT_JSON_APP;
```

Comment: Lo he puesto como dices pero me esta marcando ORA-01830: la máscara de formato de fecha termina antes de convertir toda la cadena de entrada

Comment: @AmairaniFernanda cambia el formato a: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'

Comment: Ya quedo, sólo que la variable FECHA la puse como nvarchar2 y así ya se pudo. Muchas gracias

Comment: @cambiaste el formato a : 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS' ?

Comment: así lo tenia, sólo que si dejaba la variable FECHA como date en el sp me marcaba el error. Sólo que ahorita me di cuenta que desde android me toma horas pasadas